# Prolog fail meaning

Tags: prolog

I would like to know what exactly does it mean?

```
pred(_):-fail.
```

I have read some articles but I couldn't find anything about similar syntax.

EDIT: (broader context)
`pred3(A, B) :- pred(A), pred2(B).` pred2 is same as pred

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i have just edited my post

Comment: If there are no other rules or facts for `pred/1`, then `pred3(A, B)` will always fail because `pred(A)` will always fail due to the rule, `pred(_) :- fail`.

Comment: What part of the `pred(_) :- fail.` syntax are you uncertain about?

Comment: `pred(_):-fail.` Whatever(`_`) you pass to pred\1 it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

pred(_):- fail. could be used for a psuedo if else statement. For example

```
%if the number = 2
pred(2) :-
     write('correct number recieved').

%else if number = 5    
pred(5):-
     write('close enough for me').

%else we only want a two so fail
pred(_):-
      fail.
```